# why is my code of calculating average from an array not working?

Tags: c

I had a large sample size so I made a big array and read the file's data into it but my code is not compiling for some reason

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("elephantArray.txt", "r");
    if( file == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int weight;
    int weightSet[10000];
    int i = 0;
    while(fscanf(file, "%d\t", &weightSet[i]) != EOF){
        printf("%d\n", weightSet[i]);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    int j = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int size=0;
    for(int j=0; j<10000;j++){
        while(weightSet[j]!=NULL){
            sum = sum + weightSet[j];
            size++;
        }
    }
    int average= sum/size;
    printf(average);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error expected const char but argument is of int type and I am confused why?

Comment: Because you can't call `printf` with just an `int`. See https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: What do you expect this to do: `while(weightSet[j]!=NULL){`

Comment: Tip: After reading from the file, the variable `i` holds the number of valid array members. Use it....

Comment: @4386427 the file had too many numbers which I couldnt count so I thought let me initialise a very long array , the idea behind that line was that once all the contents of the file are put in the array rest of the array positions will be null and I dont want the null positions to be added in the size as that way the average will not be correct

Comment: `for(int j=0; j<10000;j++)` : what do you think happens if the file contains less (or more)  than 10000 values?

Comment: Also please edit and show the  verbatim first 5-6 lines of "elephantArray.txt".

Comment: `rest of the array positions will be null` No they will not. They will be uninitialized int's.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
while(fscanf(file, "%d\t", &weightSet[i]) != EOF){
```

is not 100% correct. You should

1. Check for `i` not exceeding array size
2. Compare `scanf` return value with 1
3. Drop the `\t` as it doesn't do anything useful.

So do

```
while(i < 10000 && fscanf(file, "%d", &weightSet[i]) == 1){
```

The reason for "error expected const char but argument is of int type" is simple:

```
printf(average); ---> printf("%d\n", average);
```

That said, your code for calculating the sum is wrong, i.e. this code will not work:

```
   for(int j=0; j<10000;j++){

    while(weightSet[j]!=NULL){     // This will be an endless loop...
        sum = sum + weightSet[j];
        size++;
    }
   }
```

Instead use `i` in the for loop as `i` holds the number of valid array elements:

```
   sum = 0;
   for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
        sum = sum + weightSet[j];
   }
   if (i != 0) {
       int average = sum/i;
       printf("%d\n", average);
   }
   else
   {
       puts("No integers found in the file");
   }
```

BTW: Notice that calculating an average as an integer may give some surpricing result.

Comment: BTW: `#include <stdlib.h>` is missing too

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("elephantArray.txt", "r");
    if( file == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int weight;
    int weightSet[10000];
    int i = 0;
    while(fscanf(file, "%d\t", &weightSet[i]) == 1){
        printf("%d\n", weightSet[i]);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    int j =0;
    int sum=0;
    int size=0;
    for(j=0; j<i;j++){
        sum = sum + weightSet[j];
    }
    if (i != 0) {
       int average= sum/i;
       printf("%d\n", average);
    }
    else
    {
       puts("No integers found in the file");
    }
    int average= sum/size;
    printf("%d\n", average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).